# Bootstrap iPhone 5 Landscape Orientation Media Query Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do some more detailed customizing than bootstrap standard media queries.Here is the code that i am using to target iPhone 5 Landscape Orientation browsers:

```
/* iPhone 5 in landscape -----------*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
                                body {
                                        background-color:khaki;
                                     }
}
```

but it is not working ! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

from: http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/